# Summaries two column with 0 value on a specific column

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I'm sure this is fairly unusual situation, and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm trying to report on a table of SQL DB; this table has field called sample_bucket which defines which size is being used as sample, within this table we have size01-size24 column.
Also we have another field called "Type" and I need to choose between type A and B.

I've used following code on tow "Formula Fields" to extract the sizeXX base on the content of sample_bucket as follow:

formula1:

```
if {zzpom.Type}= "A" and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=1 then {zzpom.SIZE01}
else
if {zzpom.Type}= "A" and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=2 then {zzpom.SIZE02}
else
.
.
if {zzpom.Type}= "A" and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=24 then {zzpom.SIZE24}
else 0
```

and also

formula2:

```
if {zzpom.Type}= "B" and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=1 then {zzpom.SIZE01}
else
if {zzpom.Type}= "B" and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=2 then {zzpom.SIZE02}
else
.
.
if {zzpom.Type}= "B" and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=24 then {zzpom.SIZE24}
else 0
```

And I filtered on `{formula1}<>0 or {formula2}<>0` but when I run the report I get two columns instead on one:

```
formula1   formula2  |  formula1   formula2  
  6.5         0      |     0         12
```

I tried to summarize the report but looks like CR runs these formula in spread!

I need to consolidate these two columns to:

```
formula1   formula2  
  6.5         12
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If this is within CR then I'm guessing that the formulas are in separate formula fields.  I would combine the formulas into a single field.

```
if ({zzpom.Type}= "A" or {zzpom.Type}= "B") and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=1 then {zzpom.SIZE01}
else if ({zzpom.Type}= "A" or {zzpom.Type}= "B") and {zzpom.SAMPLE_BK}=2 then {zzpom.SIZE02}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think I would not work, to make it clearer I've made a sample of the DB as follow:    
  
Sample_bk | Type | … | size_6 | size_7 | size_8 |  
   7   |  A   | … |   ..   |   6.5  |   ..   |  
   7   |  B   | … |   ..   |   12   |   ..   |   

The condition is the same for both except the type would be different and meanwhile I’m picking up the Data from same field name such as size_7 because sample_bk = 7.